# Basic web application using Saxon API and IKVM throws exception

Tags: saxon, ikvm

I created a basic .NET 4.0 application and referenced the Saxon assemblies. Here is the list of dll's I referenced in the project.

saxon9.dll
saxon9api.dll
IKVM.OpenJDK.ClassLibrary.dll
IKVM.Runtime.dll

The code for the application is as follows:

```
Sub Main()

    Console.WriteLine("Trying to instantiate SaxonProcessor...")
    Try
        Dim SaxonProcessor As Saxon.Api.Processor = New Saxon.Api.Processor()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " & ex.Message & ex.StackTrace)
        Console.Read()
    End Try

    Console.WriteLine("Saxon instantiated successfully!")
    Console.Read()

End Sub
```

When I run this application on our IIS machine, I get the following output:

Trying to instantiate SaxonProcessor...
Saxon instantiated successfully!

I then created a basic web application project and referenced the same files as the windows application. I deployed the web application to a virtual directory that contains all the referenced assemblies. I put the following code inside my Default.aspx page:

Public Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Response.Write("Trying to instantiate SaxonProcessor...")

    Try
        Dim SaxonProcessor As Saxon.Api.Processor = New Saxon.Api.Processor()
        Response.Write("Saxon instantiated successfully!")
    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write("Error: " & ex.Message & ex.StackTrace)
    End Try

End Sub
```

End Class

When I load the page, it gives me this exception:

Trying to instantiate SaxonProcessor...Error: The type initializer for 'IKVM.NativeCode.java.lang.Thread' threw an exception. at IKVM.NativeCode.java.lang.Class.forName0(String name, Boolean initialize, Object loader) at java.lang.Class.forName0(String , Boolean , ClassLoader ) at java.lang.Class.forName(String className) at net.sf.saxon.dotnet.DotNetExtensionFunctionFactory.class$(String x0) at net.sf.saxon.dotnet.DotNetExtensionFunctionFactory..ctor(Configuration config) at net.sf.saxon.dotnet.DotNetPlatform.initialize(Configuration config) at net.sf.saxon.Configuration.init() at net.sf.saxon.Configuration..ctor() at Saxon.Api.Processor..ctor() at BealSaxxon._Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\u0147101\Desktop\BealSaxxon\BealSaxxon\Default.aspx.vb:line 9

FULL STACKTRACE FROM IIS MACHINE:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'IKVM.NativeCode.java.lang.Thread' threw an exception. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'java.io.BufferedInputStream' threw an exception. ---> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater can not access a member of class java.io.BufferedInputStream with modifiers "volatile" ---> java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater can not access a member of class java.io.BufferedInputStream with modifiers "volatile"
   at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.ensureMemberAccess(Class currentClass, Class memberClass, Object target, Int32 modifiers)
   at java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater.AtomicReferenceFieldUpdaterImpl..ctor(Class , Class , String )
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater.AtomicReferenceFieldUpdaterImpl..ctor(Class , Class , String )
   at java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater.newUpdater(Class tclass, Class vclass, String fieldName)
   at java.io.BufferedInputStream..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at java.io.BufferedInputStream.__<clinit>()
   at java.lang.System.initializeSystemClass()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at IKVM.NativeCode.java.lang.Thread..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at IKVM.NativeCode.java.lang.Class.forName0(String name, Boolean initialize, Object loader)
   at java.lang.Class.forName(String className)
   at net.sf.saxon.dotnet.DotNetExtensionFunctionFactory.class$(String x0)
   at net.sf.saxon.dotnet.DotNetExtensionFunctionFactory..ctor(Configuration config)
   at net.sf.saxon.dotnet.DotNetPlatform.initialize(Configuration config)
   at net.sf.saxon.Configuration.init()
   at net.sf.saxon.Configuration..ctor()
   at Saxon.Api.Processor..ctor()
   at EDG.Transforms..ctor()
   at EDG.Main..ctor(NameValueCollection applicationSettings, List`1 exceptionList)
   at EDG.EGallery..ctor(NameValueCollection ConfigurationSettings, List`1 ExceptionList)
```

Has anyone seen this exception before? I've searched extensively on Google but nobody seems to have had this specific exception. I'm thinking it's a permissions problem with IIS, but I don't know for sure. The application pool this application is running under is setup with a machine administrator.

Comment: Which IKVM version do you use?

Comment: Do you have more details of the exception like a stacktrace of the inner class?

Comment: Updated with the full stack trace of the exception we are getting from the IIS machine

Comment: The version of KVM runtime is 0.36.0.11. Keep in mind, the same version we're using on other IIS machines, are working fine. The problem almost seems configuration related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this situation, it was a product called OpNET that was interfering with apps using the JVM. Once its services and processes were stopped, the Saxon assembly worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be 2 types of causes.

- One of the IKVM dll is missing. Add all dll of IKVM to test if this solve the problem.
- IKVM is compiled for .NET 2 and not version 4. You need to add a version mapping to your app.config.

Comment: We have only ever needed IKVM.Runtime.dll and IKVM.OpenJDK.ClassLibrary.dll. Both are present. The same dll's are in effect on other IIS machines and are running without the exception.